# Customizing terminal not affecting after restart through ~/.profile

Tags: 14.04, command-line, gnome-terminal, .profile

Any welcome text, modifying PS1, aliases not working after restart.

I have to put "source ~/.profile" every new terminal i open.

Wishing for complete fix for these all to effect everytime on launching terminal.

USING Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: `~/.profile` is not sourced in non-login shells, that's why it doesn't work. You should customize the prompt in `~/.bashrc` as explained in the accepted answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: Lazy people can add  `source  $HOME/.profile`   into `.bashrc` to make that work, but that's silly and not how should be done properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `PS1` and defining aliases (and functions) should be done in `.bashrc` since this file is read at the start of **every** *interactive non-login shell*.

`.profile` is only read at the start of a *login shell* and should really only be used to set to set environment variables and other settings that should be inherited by child processes launched by the shell.

For more information, see Section 6.2 of the Bash manual, [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html).

To ensure that the Bash-specific settings are also set for login shells, the
default `.profile` for Ubuntu contains the following lines:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

See also: [this excellent answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46856/22812) to the [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell)